# No way to "Request Improvement" in response to a factual error?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, documentation

I just followed a link to Documentation after somebody on Q&A linked to an Example there. The example contained a minor factual error. (*Of course* it did.) I downvoted it, and the resulting popup invited me to *Request Improvement*. But none of the possible categories in the *Request Improvement* dialog apply, so I gave up:

[image: Request improvement dialog screenshot]

These categories of "improvement" reasons cover only Examples that are completely and profoundly rotten to the point of being useless or worse. But the button says "Request Improvement", not "This Example is irredeemable garbage and should be purged from the earth". Surely there should be a category here that allows us to report factual inaccuracies?

(And for that matter, why are there two categories of "improvement" request (*not an example* and *very low quality*) that are explicitly requests to completely delete the Example? That ain't what I understand an "improvement" to be.)

Comment: I often look at new contributions to see if they are correct but I really do not want to edit docs so I would love this.  At least for right now you can leave a comment with the new discussion feature.

Comment: If you see a factual error, why not edit it out?

Comment: @TravisJ knowing that something is incorrect is not always the same as knowing what the correct thing is.

Comment: @artem and even if I *do* know what the correct thing is, I may be able to write up an explanation of why the current content is wrong faster than I can fix it - which especially matters if I'm at work, and can't honourably spend any significant length of time editing stuff on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not understanding something. This isn't Q&A, right? So why do you need an explanation of why something is wrong in an edit? (Other than the reason for the edit - and usually I'd think "The example code was incorrect." would suffice.) I do agree with @artem, but that doesn't sound like the case here.

Comment: Well, downvoting the example seems to be the tool to use... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Braiam the tool to use how for what? The entire point of this question is that none of the available reasons when downvoting can be used to describe a factual error with the Example, leaving no way to ask for such an error to be corrected.

Comment: Who says you have to actually spell out the reason you are downvoting? The whole reason is "optional", isn't it?

Comment: @Braiam nobody said that I "have" to, but I want to be able to do so in order to help improve the content on the site - especially given that a downvote without explanation literally achieves *nothing* in Documentation, unlike in Q&A where it at least helps order posts and indicate their credibility. Seriously, what's difficult to understand here?

Comment: @Braiam the reason is optional, downvoting is optional, participation in general is optional. That doesn't mean that if someone actively wants to improve the content on the site, they should be prevented from doing so. This is a reasonable request, I don't understand the aversion here.

Comment: Then, why would there be a downvote bottom if you can't downvote a wrong example. The tool is right there. USE IT!

Comment: @Braiam seriously, what's wrong with you? I *did* use the downvote button, and said so in the first paragraph of my post, and again in the comments, and in any case whether I did or not has no bearing on this feature request, and regardless of all *that* there's no need at all to YELL INSTRUCTIONS AT ME IN ALL CAPS WITH EXCLAMATION MARKS! Why does every interaction I have with you on Meta seem to descend into a multi-hour protracted exchange of incoherent rudeness like this? I don't claim to be the most agreeable person in the world, but I don't have this problem consistently with anyone else.

Comment: Then, what else you want. You already did what you could, do not feel bad because you couldn't do more. The "improvement request" is just a fancy flag modal. In fact, I would call it a flag modal. Obviously it wasn't meant as "improvement request". The downvote dialog actually had a free form text where you could tell what was wrong, but that was scrapped in preference to merge it with the flag dialog. The tools are made so that one can not point out inaccuracies in the most public way, I find more easy to just scrap the entire example instead of sitting on my fist. Downvoting helps with that.

Comment: @Braiam "Who says you have to actually spell out the reason you are downvoting" - unless I misunderstand something, that dialog appeared on its own, literally asking him to spell out the reason for downvoting.

Comment: @aw04 it is "optional". I can downvote and ignore the dialog.

Comment: For what it's worth, the goal was to encourage you to just fix factual errors rather than hope someone else would do it. It's usually inefficient to try to tell someone else to fix a problem you notice.

Answer (score -6):

I'd say mark very low quality and move on. There's hardly lower quality than well presented misleading answers (or other things).

Comment: This question is asking about Docs.SO examples, not Stack Overflow questions or answers.

Comment: @TinyGiant: My answer stands all the same.

Comment: Docs.SO examples are different than Stack Overflow answers in so many ways. One of the big differences is that examples are wiki-style, so editing is preferable over outright deletion in most cases, unless the entire example is outright unnecessary.

Comment: The way to measure quality is all the same. Post score as proxy for quality. If there is a high score post with poor quality then is not the system fault, but humans that has such a crappy insight.

Comment: Part of the definition of "low quality" is "it is unlikely to be salvageable through editing and should be removed".   That's a pretty severe dismissal, and doesn't make sense at all for a minor factual error.